# Ruby on Rails - User object showing nil fields even though they are filled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, authentication, model

I'm having a weird problem with getting my user registration to work in Rails. When I create a user, it will show all its fields but the password_digest being nil, but when I type something like "u.email", the email will show up. However, it doesn't want to save the user, I assume because it thinks it doesn't meet all the validation requirements.

Some rails console fiddling:

```
irb(main):003:0> u = User.new({username: "askddkasd", email: "a@a.a", 
    password: "meowmeowmeow", password_confirmation: "meowmeowmeow"})
=> #<User id: nil, username: nil, email: nil, password_digest: 
    "$2a$10$eWhQdOCLXfmcGrrRdigSFeENUeAEaQ6xJ7U08k7g3gZ...", salt: nil>
irb(main):002:0> u.save
    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = BINARY 'askddkasd' LIMIT 1
      User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'a@a.a' LIMIT 1
    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
irb(main):022:0> u.username
=> "askddkasd"
irb(main):023:0> u.email
=> "a@a.a"
```

As you can see, the fields appear nil, but I can access their values.
Here is my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password

    attr_accessor :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

    validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
    validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
    validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
    validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create

    after_save :clear_password

    def password=(password)
        self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
    end

    def is_password?(password)
        BCrypt::Password.new(self.password_digest) == password
    end

    def clear_password
        self.password = nil
    end

    def self.authenticate(username_or_email="", login_password="")
      if username_or_email.include? '@'
        user = User.find_by_email(username_or_email)
      else
        user = User.find_by_username(username_or_email)
      end

      if user && user.is_password?(login_password)
        return user
      end
      return false
    end
end
```

Has anyone had this problem before? If so, how did you resolve it?

Update: Could it be because I have username and email as accessors? So those values don't actually get to the username/email fields to be stored in the database?

Comment: What in `u.errors`?

Comment: `#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa075241e50 @base=#<User id: nil, username: nil, email: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$WH5OUfqx4vYDoeD3nMlhR.rm9F7O6QSIg.Rd9zcu215...", salt: nil>, @messages={:password_confirmation=>["doesn't match Password"], :password=>["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}, @details={:password_confirmation=>[{:error=>:confirmation, :attribute=>"Password"}], :password=>[{:error=>:too_short, :count=>6}]}>`

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it rolls back after this statement in the log

```
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'a@a.a' LIMIT 1
```

makes me think that there is already a user in the database with this email address. You can figure out for sure what the issue is by calling `u.valid?` and then `u.errors`.

Comment: There are 0 entries in the users table.